# Header is not automatically generated by wizard in qt-creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

today I wanted to start diving in into QT by doing [the official notepad tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html). It is said that the header will be generated automatically to this:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Notepad;
}


class Notepad : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Notepad(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Notepad();

private slots:
    void on_actionNew_triggered();

    void on_actionOpen_triggered();

    void on_actionSave_triggered();

    void on_actionSave_as_triggered();

    void on_actionPrint_triggered();

    void on_actionExit_triggered();

    void on_actionCopy_triggered();

    void on_actionCut_triggered();

    void on_actionPaste_triggered();

    void on_actionUndo_triggered();

    void on_actionRedo_triggered();

    void on_actionFont_triggered();

    void on_actionBold_triggered();

    void on_actionUnderline_triggered();

    void on_actionItalic_triggered();

    void on_actionAbout_triggered();

private:
    Ui::Notepad *ui;
    QString currentFile;
};
```

But after saving and even restartin qtcreator I'm getting this:

```
#ifndef NOTEPAD_H
#define NOTEPAD_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Notepad;
}

class Notepad : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Notepad(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Notepad();

private:
    Ui::Notepad *ui;
};

#endif // NOTEPAD_H
```

Is there any information file about configuration I could provide to allow you to help me? Or anything in the settings?

As far as I can see there is some problem with the Design .ui tool.

Comment: Where does it say that: *header will be generated automatically* ?, then do you think that by magic the IDE knows what you want to do ?, well no, what you should do that header is created by editing the .ui, please read the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html

Comment: I edited the .ui according to the official tutorial. But in the header file nothing happens after saving.

Comment: Have you created the slots in the QActions of QMenuBar through Qt Designer ?, I can not see it, can show the .ui file. Please read the link I have provided and review all the examples and annexes that you indicate.

Comment: @eyllanes, I think the documentation is indeed misleading. It states: _The wizard generated a header file for the Notepad class that has the necessary #includes, a constructor, a destructor, and the Ui object. The file looks as follows:_ and then the same code is shown, which is actually not generated by the wizard.

Comment: @scopchanov As the documentation of the examples has an order, it is different from the documentation of the classes. To understand the examples you must have an order, if in an example Qt Designer is used, then first learn to use Qt Designer and for that you must read the examples of Qt Designer

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this issue. It seems that the tutorial is incomplete. I will fix this.

Comment: @eyllanesc, you are of course right. I also believe that it was good that the flaw in the documentation has been mentioned. Probably it should be reported to Qt as well in order to be corrected.

Comment: After inserting the menu the changes still don't apply to the header file.